# j2me : cannot run application

Tags: eclipse, java-me

I have problem trying to run an application.

When I click on "Launch as emulated Java ME JAD"
this message shown :

> com.sun.kvem.midletsuite.InvalidJadException: Reason = 22
>   The manifest or the application descriptor MUST contain the attribute: MIDlet-1

But it is run true when I click on "Launch as emulated Java ME MIDlet"

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the more self-explanatory errors.  Your JAD must contain the attribute `MIDlet-1` as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_(file_format)).